# Is it possible to detect if help file is contained in the setup file (msi or exe)?

Tags: installation, inno-setup, installshield

I would like to know how can I detect if help file is contained in setup file for windows platform application (msi or exe). Is there any method to get this information without installing the software first ?

Of course setup file can be created by many setup makers like innosetup, installshield and so on. So I wonder if there is some universal method to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an MSI based install it would be very easy.   For example you can use the Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller interop via C# to open the MSI as an InstallPackageClass then access it's Files collection to see if it contains the file you care about.

For a Non-MSI based install, there is no universal way and in most cases, no way period.  See, that's kind of the point of MSI: to have a standards based package rich in meta data to be able to see what it's doing.  When you do some proprietary script driven installer you lose that openness.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a MSI file, open it up using Orca, and you can view file names.

For both of them, you should be able to do an administrative install, which would extract the files, but not register anything. Depending on where the exe came from, doing an administrative install changes, since each vendor(installshield, innosetup, etc) has their own way to run an administrative install.

for a MSI it's simply

`msiexec /a <msi_filename>`

For an exe you'll have to look up how to pass the /a argument.